# Cobertura equivalent available for C# .NET?

Tags: c#, .net, code-coverage, cobertura

Is there a [Cobertura](http://cobertura.sourceforge.net/) (or other code coverage tool) equivalent for C# .NET?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's [NCover](http://www.ncover.com/), but's not free. There's an old, community edition somewhere on the site, maybe it will be sufficient for you.

Comment: I would say the quality, features and support on NCover is worth the price. There isn't always a free lunch available.

Comment: I agree. Sadly, I worked in a team that couldn't afford NCover, and that's why I mentioned free version. I believe it's better to use community edition than not use code coverage at all.

Answer (score 2):

You may try **[OpenCover](https://github.com/sawilde/opencover)** the successor of *PartCover*.

Answer (score 1):

If you need a free version, [PartCover](http://sourceforge.net/projects/partcover/files/) is an open source alternative.

Answer (score 0):

[SD C# Test Coverage](http://www.semanticdesigns.com/Products/TestCoverage/CSharpTestCoverage.html).  Not free.